# How to make a video open and play on button click in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm very new to iOS and have very little experience.
Please could someone show me how to code my app so a video open and play on button click? I can´t find out how to do this anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think this code will help you to open Movie player.

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/somefile.mp4"];
movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieController];
[movieController.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: His question is with swift, not objective-c

Answer (score 1):

inside button click event

```
    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
```